# Why do I keep getting a "warning: comparison between pointer and integer error"?

Tags: c

Does anyone know why my program doesn't read from my delimited file? I thought it would print everything from my delimited file after the program ran through my `printPropertyListing()` method at the bottom but instead it gives me the error message warning `"warning: comparison between pointer and integer"`. It's telling me the error is on the beginning line of my for loop in the main method. Any solutions please?

Here is what my delimited file looks like:

---

```
123 Cherry Tree Drive#330#Condo#2#1#275900#Toronto#
14 Leaside Lane#N/A#House#4#2#445500#Brampton#
2478 Waterfront Avenue#N/A#House#5#3#899900#Mississauga#
7 Lucky Lane#1206#Condo#3#2#310000#Toronto#
51 West Street#32#Townhouse#4#2#450000#Brampton#
193 Crystal Road#1519#Condo#1#1#250750#Toronto#
3914 Tangerine Terrace#N/A#House#3#1#427750#Mississauga#
10 Redding Road#N/A#House#4#2#512350#Toronto#
76 Old School Avenue#227#Townhouse#3#2#475000#Toronto#
90 Brookhaven Terrace#N/A#House#4#2#512750#Brampton#
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char buildingType[10];
    int numBedrooms;
    int numBathrooms;
    }Propertylisting;

typedef struct {

Propertylisting propertylisting;
    char address[100];
    char unitNum [10];
    char city [50];
    int listPrice;
} Listing;

void parseListings(FILE *in, Listing listing[], int arraySize); 
void printPropertyListing(Listing l);


int main()
{
    Listing listing[10];
    FILE *fp = fopen("PropertyListings.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Could not open file!");
        exit(1);
    } 
    else 
    {
        parseListings(fp, listing, 10);

        if (listing == 0) 
        {
            printf("No Property data found.");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("\nNumber of listings in file: %d\n\n", listing);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < listing; i++) 
        {
            printPropertyListing(listing[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);

    }
    return 0;
}

void parseListings(FILE *in, Listing listing[], int arraySize)
{
    // Holds the current index of the Listing array
    int n = 0;

    // Set value as empty string
    char line[256];

    // A token pointer that the strtok() function returns
    char *token;

    char *delimiter = "#";

    while (!feof(in)&& n > arraySize) 
    {
        fgets(line, 256, in);

        // Read the address
        token = strtok(line, delimiter);
        strcpy(listing[n].address, token);

        // Read the unitNum
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        strcpy(listing[n].unitNum, token);

        // Read the building typede
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        strcpy(listing[n].propertylisting.buildingType, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        int numBedrooms = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        listing[n].propertylisting.numBedrooms = numBedrooms;

        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        int numBathrooms = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        listing[n].propertylisting.numBathrooms = numBathrooms;

        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        int listPrice = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        listing[n].listPrice = listPrice;

        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        strcpy(listing[n].city, token);
        n++;
    }

    return n;
}

void printPropertyListing(Listing l) 
{
    printf("%s %s %s\n%s %d %d %d\n\n", 
        l.address, 
        l.unitNum, 
        l.city, 
        l.propertylisting.buildingType, 
        l.propertylisting.numBedrooms, 
        l.propertylisting.numBathrooms, 
        l.listPrice);
}
```

Comment: Because `i` is an integer, and `listing` is an array (which becomes a pointer).

Comment: Does this actually compile? You're returning an `int` (`n`) from a `void` function, among other things.

Comment: Among the other bugs, `while(!feof())` is almost always a bug because the EOF indicator is only set *after* an input operation hit EOF, never before. Usually this means the loop performs an extra iteration with something empty or undefined. Apart from that , `n > arraySize` should probably be `n < arraySize`, no?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your for loop:

`for (i = 0; i < listing; i++)`

*i* is of type `int` and *listing* is of type `Listing [10];`

Comment: `if (listing == 0)` seems like another instance of this (which may pass without a compiler warning since `0` is a special case; but is almost certainly not what OP intended)

Comment: Most definitely. I just spotted this one first :) the OP should probably enable the '-W' flag on his/hers compiler to prevent these mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, your `listing` variable is an array (which is actually a pointer to the start of a block of memory being used as an array). This means you are attempting to compare a pointer to an int, which does not make sense.

It looks like you are trying to compare to the size of the array, and since your `parseListings` function already returns the number of listings it has parsed, you can instead do the following:

```
    int numListings = parseListings(fp, listing, 10);

    if (numListings == 0) {
        printf("No Property data found.");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nNumber of listings in file: %d\n\n", numListings);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numListings; i++) {
        printPropertyListing(listing[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

You will note that I changed a few other locations where you were also using the `listing` variable, but I suspect you had wanted to check against the number of listings.

In addition to this, there is the points which Jens made about other bugs in your program, which would make this the perfect time to learn about the `while 1: ... break;` paradigm.

```
while (n < arraySize) {
    fgets(line, 256, in);

    if(feof(in)) {
        break;
    }
```

Credit to other people for pointing out all of these bugs; I have just attempted to formulate all of their responses into a single coherent guide to things you should consider for improving this code specifically and all of your code in general.

Edit: additionally, the return type of parseListing should be changed to int in order to match the fact that you `return n;`

Comment: thank you, I dont think it will work thought becuase my parseListings return type is void. I will try this thought and post back my results

Comment: Good point, that is something else that should be changed. Your parseListings does return n but declares a void return type. That should have generated a compiled warning at least. Change the return type.